# How valuable is CFI hours outside USA?

Tags: airliner, faa, pilots, airlines, cfi

CFI serves as an excellent pathway to the airline industry. However, if I don't have the necessary paperwork to remain in the US and work, how does accumulating 1500 hours in single-engine aircraft contribute to advancing into airlines beyond the USA?

I often come across LinkedIn posts from Asian airlines, many of which specify a requirement of 200 or more turboprop hours.

Having obtained a FAA frozen ATPL, I find myself uncertain about the next course of action.

Comment: I feel this is better off asked in a discussion forum rather than this specific question and answer page. My 2 cents though: hours are hours and you should be aiming for any job you can get. That might not be an airline job right away. Start by looking in the country you already have the right to work in. Where I'm from in Australia the typical airline job ad requires 500 total time but 250 multi-command hours. If you only have 1500 hours instructing in a Cessna 172 you won't get the job (exceptions apply). Some Asian and European airlines will take you at 200 hours though. It varies so much.